# console.log -> Document { ... }

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

When I apply "console.log" on an JS Object, the console output this thing :

```
I20170421-14:54:09.786(2)? Document {
I20170421-14:54:09.787(2)?   _id: 'KQ7mdidtcxsQsqNjr',
I20170421-14:54:09.787(2)?   name: 'eos test',
I20170421-14:54:09.787(2)?   number: 69526,
I20170421-14:54:09.788(2)?   part: 'bus',
I20170421-14:54:09.788(2)?   active: true,
I20170421-14:54:09.789(2)?   cron: 6,
```

What is this 'Document' ??? How I can remove to comapre this Object with the same without 'Document'...

I'm lost !

This document is an output of 'findOne'. I use Meteor with some packages (mongo@1.1.16, aldeed:simple-schema, aldeed:collection2, mdg:validated-method, mdg:validation-error, dburles:collection-helpers).

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show us what you mean when you say `When I apply "console.log" on an JS Object`. What is the actual code?

Comment: You can't compare(x === y) complex objects unless they're referenced.

Comment: I can remove this 'Document' with underscore.js : `_.object(_.pairs(myObj))`... I don't think it's _the_ good way...

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans my code : `const eqptDb = Equipments.findOne(eqptId);       console.log(eqptDb);` and the beginning of the result : 
`Document {
   _id: '9PeFcjA4nbyx5MDry',
   name: 'praesentium',
   number: 33596,`

Comment: @kristjanreinhold The comparison is perform with `chai.assert.deepEqual()` or `_.isMatch` of underscore.js

Comment: The library you're using returns an object with additional metadata. Do a compare on what you actually want to match with eachother (so: be more specific!).

Comment: Thanks @JeffHuijsmans 
Is not possible to remove this metadata ?

Answer (score 0):

You could compare manually (obj2.field1 === obj2.field1) or just use JSON.stringify in both objects and compare the resulting string.

But in your case I think you are not retrieving the object from mongo as you should.
Use fetch() after the query: DocumentCollection.find({}).fetch() or just .findOne() instead.

Also, if you want to compare 2 Meteor documents, you can use:

_.isEqual(doc1, doc2) (underscore)

Comment: In fact, I use `findOne` but I may compare an object retreive to the DB with an other Object (that is not beginning with 'Document')... but the equality is false due to 'Document'... (I don't understand what is this 'Document'...)

Comment: I think Document is the way chrome shows you the object